# Magento: Get yes/no untranslated values in attributes.phtml

Tags: magento

I have a multilingual ans I want to test if I have a "yes/no" attribute, but I get for each shop different values; for example: "Yes" for the english store, and "Oui" for the french one...

How can I get the attribute option value like a boolean (1 or 0) ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use following code.

$_product->getData('attribute_code')